# Facebook chat bot separate from normal chat

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

How can I have a chatbot separate from normal chat on my page? I am experimenting with a chatbot, I created a bot with webhooks configured and the bot is working fine as I expected(it's in test mode) but to interact with a bot I have to use the same chat window which is used for my support. Right now my page is using FB chat as a support desk, now I have seen pages using two different chat windows one for messages and one for the bot. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is designed by Facebook to be what you're looking for "Handover protocol"

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol